# How to hide element in 2 seconds in React

Tags: reactjs, hide, tailwind-css, snackbar

I use Tailwind-css and React and want to hide div-element after 2 seconds.
The user press the button and a snackbar apears for 2 sec to show that the suggestion was sent.
I use *setTimeout* but it is not correct variant.
Function Snackbar get props whether **snackbar open** (*snackbar = true*), **message on the snackbar** (*suggestResponse.message*) and should sent if **snackbarClose** (*false*)

```
const SnackbarResult = ({
  snackbar,
  snackbarClose,
  suggestResponse,
}: ISnackbarProps) => {
  if (snackbar) {
    setTimeout(() => snackbarClose, 2000);
  }
  if (!snackbar) return null;
  return (
    <div className="bg-green-500 fixed right-2 bottom-1 font-medium p-2 md:p-5">
      {suggestResponse.message}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put `setTimeout` inside the useEffect so you can clear the timeout when component re-render or un mount.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (snackbar) {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => snackbarClose(), 2000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }
}, [snackbar]);
```

Comment: Thank you. How I could forget about useEffect!